# yum syntax to get jboss on centos?

Tags: jboss, centos, yum

What's the syntax to get JBoss AS (latest, say 7.1.1) on CentOS (latest, 6.5)? I tried

```
su
yum install jbossas
```

but get the error

```
No package jbossas available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Either I need to add some repos to yum or the package name is wrong. I understand I can just unzip the .zip into `/bin/` per [this post](http://opensourcearchitect.co/tutorials/installing-jboss-7-1-on-centos-6), but that would lead to messy/orphaned files in upgrades, so I'm looking for open, community repos that might have the jboss-as binaries.

Answer (score 1):

So far my knowledge, you can not do this using yum at CentOS. Also, you can not upgrade from one version of JBoss into another one automatically(like any software or compiler do it automatically). Things are totally different here. For example JBoss 5.1 is having a totally different directory architecture compare to JBoss 7.1.

Comment: I think you're right ... `yum install jbossas` was alive till about JBoss AS 3 (or 4). Seems like they've killed it off now ...

Comment: Use wget instead.  See here:  http://opensourcearchitect.co/tutorials/installing-jboss-7-1-on-centos-6